# DropShadow effect on pie chart

Tags: wpf, toolkit

I want to do a pie chart with a DropShadow effect, so i've tried to put the effect on the PieDataPoint object but it didn't work - instead of heaving a shadow of the pie every slice of the pie draw its own shadow on its neighbors, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Comment: ok I'v solved the problem, the question can be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I set the DropShadow effect on the EdgePanel inside the chart's template and it worked.

```
     <Charting:Chart.Template>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="Charting:Chart">
                <Border>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect
                                    ShadowDepth = "5"
                                    Direction = "330"
                                    Color = "Gray"
                                    Opacity = "0.5"
                                    BlurRadius = "10">
                                </DropShadowEffect>
                            </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel.Effect>
                        </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>

                            <charting:Legend x:Name="Legend" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                        </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Charting:Chart.Template>
```